# How to Integrate LinqToSql with Metadata Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd, data-annotations

I'm just getting started on a new MVC project, and like a good boy I am trying to defer going to the DB for as long as possible. Here's the scoop:

1. I'm planning on using the ComponentModel.DataAnnotations decorations.
2. I'm also planning on using LinqToSql

Is is possible to write a unit test against the DataAnnotations metadata classes? I don't want to put a schema such until as late as possible but I'd still like to write tests to validate the model.

Any ideas on a good approach? Maybe something completely different?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do u wish to make some POCO classes that have DataAnnotations on the public properties (eg. a string FullName is required and has a max length of 100, etc) .. and if so .. u wish to unit test this public proprety ... OR ... you wish to unit test a DataAnnotation (which is crazy talk, considering that's part of the framework, so it's implied it's ok

Comment: Yeah, not well phrased. The first option is what I want, but what I want to avoid is mapping every property from the LinqToSql classes over to the POCO objects by hand. So what I tried to do instead was create a MetaData class for the L2S class and apply the Annotations, but they never fired. So, I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad Wilson wrote a great blog post about using DataAnnotations and unit testing them; http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/index.html

The gist of the testing strategy is this:

1. Write a test to check to make sure you are using the DataAnnotationsModelBinder as the default binder.
2. Use reflection to make sure the DataAnnotation attributes you have decorated the model properties with are what you expect.
3. When testing the Edit or Create controller actions, artificially inject ModelErrors to test that you are handling them as expected.

The rationale is that you treat System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations like a piece of infrastructure and just test how you have utilized it.